# Can I apply L'Hospital's rule to $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt2πx}{e^x}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, definition, epsilon-delta

I have the following limit

> $$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt2πx}{e^x}$$
>   My question is: should I apply l'hôpital or directly tend to 0.

Comment: Are you sure about what you wrote? It seems like the argument of limit does not depend on $x$... Did you mean $n \to \infty$?

Comment: @the_candyman sry its true, i correct it

Comment: You can use l'Hopital's rule immediately, or know that exponentials beat linear functions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should apply L'Hospital,but you must apply it when $x \to + \infty$ because in this case you will have the undetermined form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$.

So the limit will be zero.

From this you can understand that $e^x$ goes to infinity much more quickly than $x$.

But when $x \to - \infty$ we have that the limit is $-\infty$

So in this case you can compute the limit directly.